# Multi column searching

Tags: mysql

I have real estate website. Currently my table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
 `property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `property_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `seller_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `transaction_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `price` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `area` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bedrooms` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `bathrooms` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `listing_images` text NOT NULL,
 `list_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `activated` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `property_status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reviewed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In the search properties page, there is a form that allows users to filter by property type,seller type, maximum price, area, max & min bedrooms,bathrooms etc to narrow it. I tried to optimize it by creating index on each field, but it is very slow. What is the correct way to optimize this?

Comment: I guess that the user can choose any combination of columns. If yes, then it is [kitchen sink procedure](http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/) Idea: get  the most used scenarios (like 3-5 paths) and create queries that search using only that set of columns with index that cover entire query. For the rest I would build dynamically prepared statement.

Comment: ^-- Agreed.  Determine the most commonly used filters (the >80% use case) and provide "basic searches" in your UX which make use of those filters, indexing as needed for those.  Then have a separate "advanced search" which allows searching on the remaining unindexed fields as well.

Comment: "In the search properties page, there is a form that allows users to filter by property type,seller type, maximum price, area, max & min bedrooms,bathrooms etc to narrow it" Problem with this is that you need to know the search path to construct a amount multi column indexes.. What if you index single columns and use delivered tables to get the information you need to search on something like this. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eC2fuKxin9pHL44dE2Y81G/1 ..

Comment: Thank you guys. LukaszSzozda, video link was helpful. @David and RaymondNijland  I was thinking about making select box with some default value to start with. so the main required  columns will not be empty at all times and i can index them. will that be good UX? Thanks in advance